# Change Language of Rangepicker with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

[enter image description here][1]
Hi I am using Rangepicker from antd and wanted to change language of month and days with Config provider I am able to set the place holder to french but am unable to set the months and days to different language.
Please let me know should I import a different file or should the locale field should be given in a different way.

´´´ lang-js
import frFR from 'antd/lib/locale/fr_FR';

if (value==='fr'){
return (

```
            <RangePicker
              locale={frFR}
              allowClear={false}
              onChange={a => console.log("Timeframe has changed")}
              className="datepicker"
            
            />
           </ConfigProvider>
           </div>
          );
```

}
´´´

**

I am unable to post the image but a description is like

```
    *Select box:         Date de debut -> Date de in
                         Jul 2021             Aug 2021
                Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa    Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                30 1   2  3  4  5  6    1   2  3  4  5  6  7*

`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by using the moment we have to initiate the moment locally for that config provider. Config provider will wrap the locale around the components and I was using the global locale but with moment.locale('de') we will set the moments locale to german and the config provider uses that.
Go through react context docs to get a better idea of how context provider works.

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import { DatePicker } from 'antd';
import { ConfigProvider} from 'antd'; 
import deDE from 'antd/lib/locale/de_DE';
import * as moment from 'moment';
const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;
const Datepicker = ({ value}) => {
  if (value ==='de'){
    moment.locale('de', {
      months : 'Januar_Februar_Marz_April_Mai_Juni_Juli_August_September_Octobre_Novmber_December'.split('_'),
      monthsShort : 'Jan_Feb_Mar_Apr_Mai_Juni_Juli_Aug_Sept_Oct_Nov_Dez'.split('_'),
      monthsParseExact : true,
      weekdays : 'sunday_montag_dienstag_mittwoch_donnerstag_fritag_samstag'.split('_'),
      weekdaysShort : 'sun._mon._die._mit._don._fri._sam.'.split('_'),
      weekdaysMin : 'Su_Mo_Di_Mi_Do_Fr_Sa'.split('_'),
      weekdaysParseExact : true,
      longDateFormat : {
          LT : 'HH:mm',
          LTS : 'HH:mm:ss',
          L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
          LL : 'D MMMM YYYY',
          LLL : 'D MMMM YYYY HH:mm',
          LLLL : 'dddd D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
      },
      calendar : {
          sameDay : '[Aujourd’hui à] LT',
          nextDay : '[Demain à] LT',
          nextWeek : 'dddd [à] LT',
          lastDay : '[Hier à] LT',
          lastWeek : 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
          sameElse : 'L'
      },
      relativeTime : {
          future : 'dans %s',
          past : 'il y a %s',
          s : 'quelques secondes',
          m : 'une minute',
          mm : '%d minutes',
          h : 'une heure',
          hh : '%d heures',
          d : 'un jour',
          dd : '%d jours',
          M : 'un mois',
          MM : '%d mois',
          y : 'un an',
          yy : '%d ans'
      },
      dayOfMonthOrdinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|e)/,
      ordinal : function (number) {
          return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'e');
      },
      meridiemParse : /PD|MD/,
      isPM : function (input) {
          return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
      },
      // In case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
      // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example).
      // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
      //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */ ;
      // },
      meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
          return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
      },
      week: {
          dow: 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
          doy: 4  // Used to determine first week of the year.
      }
  });

    return (
      <div>
      <ConfigProvider locale={deDE} >
        <RangePicker
          allowClear={false}
          onChange={a => console.log("[Datepicker] Timeframe has changes !")}
          className="datepicker"
        />
       </ConfigProvider>
       </div>
      );
  }
```

Comment: You can just use moment's locales, rather than fully implementing your own, `import 'moment/locale/fr';` for French and `import 'moment/locale/de';` for German

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap the RangePicker on ConfigProvider

```
      <ConfigProvider locale={frFR}>
        <RangePicker
          allowClear={false}
          onChange={a => console.log("Timeframe has changed")}
          className="datepicker"
        
        />
       </ConfigProvider>
```

Comment: I did but still it is not displaying months and weeks in french

Comment: how is displaying?

Comment: I uploaded the image for the question please check above.